# Как сделать секундомер? react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, frontend

Мне надо сделать секундомер на react.js
чтобы одна кнопка начинала таймер, а вторая его останавливала и очищала( и отправляла время в базу данных) я не особо понимаю как сделать две отдельные кнопки но с одной у меня таймер выходит

example:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот код с одной кнопкой:

```
class Timer extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { minute: 0, second: 0 };
    this.updateTimer = this.updateTimer.bind(this);
    this.resetTimer = this.resetTimer.bind(this);
  }

  updateTimer() {
    this.setState((state) => {
      return {
        second: state.second === 59 ? 0 : state.second + 1,
        minute: state.second === 59 ? state.minute + 1 : state.minute
      };
    });
  }

  resetTimer() {
    this.setState({ minute: 0, second: 0 });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <p>
          {this.state.minute}:{this.state.second}
        </p>

        <Toggle updateTimer={this.updateTimer} resetTimer={this.resetTimer} />
      </>
    );
  }
}

class Toggle extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { isToggleOn: false };
    this.interval = null;
    // This binding is necessary to make `this` work in the callback
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (prevState.isToggleOn !== this.state.isToggleOn) {
      if (this.state.isToggleOn) {
        this.interval = setInterval(this.props.updateTimer, 1000);
      } else {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
        this.props.resetTimer();
      }
    }
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      isToggleOn: !prevState.isToggleOn
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
        {this.state.isToggleOn ? "OFF" : "ON"}
      </button>
    );
  }
}
```

помогите пж

Comment: В интернете полно готовых вариантов, нужно лишь [загуглить](https://www.google.com/search?q=stopwatch%20react), из которых можете взять нужное, либо либо целиком. [Вот](https://codesandbox.io/s/31rvox7ojm) например.

Answer (score 1):

Самый просто способ, добавить еще одну кнопку, с таким же обработчиком. А за счет атрибута `disabled` делаем активной нужную кнопку. Чтобы записать в базу, перед сбросом счетчика, отправляем данные на сервер.

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button
          disabled={this.state.isToggleOn}
          onClick={this.handleClick}
        >
          START
        </button>

        <button
          disabled={!this.state.isToggleOn}
          onClick={this.handleClick}
        >
          STOP
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
```